# CS50 Mario more: Want to know if the code is efficient?

Tags: c, cs50

I started the CS50 course recently, and I wanted to know if there ways to optimize the code or if it was the most efficient way to do at this stage.

```
void mariomore(int);
int main(void)
{
    int h;
    do
    {
        h = get_int("Height: ");
    }
    while (h <= 0 || h >= 9); //limiting the height of the pyramid
    mariomore(h);
}

void mariomore(int h)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) // This for is to print the # rows
    {
        for (int k = h - 1; k > i; k--) //This for is to print the spaces
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) //This for is to print the # columns
        {
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("#"); 
        printf("  "); //to print space. to valid check with $$
        for (int m = 0; m < i; m++) //to print second half of pyramid
        {
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("#\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a Stack Exchange community dedicated to code reviews. I think this question would fit there better than here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I made very few changes. You can actually remove extra `printf("#");` lines and place them in for loops by simply running loops with an additional instance.

Nevertheless, your code looks decent. You may add warnings when the user input for height is **not** between 1-9. I skipped this part as this is not what you are interested in, my guess.

```
void mariomore(int);
int main(void)
{
    int h;
    do
    {
        h = get_int("Height: ");
    }
    while (h <= 0 || h >= 9); //limiting the height of the pyramid
    mariomore(h);
}

void mariomore(int h)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) // This for is to print the # rows
    {
        for (int k = h - 1; k > i; k--) //This for is to print the spaces
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) //This for is to print the # columns
        {
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("  "); //to print space. to valid check with $$
        for (int m = 0; m < i + 1; m++) //to print second half of pyramid
        {
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```